# SQLAlchemy integrity exception

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two tables `'reservations_booking'` and `'reservations_booking_staging'`.

I'm trying to do an insert in `'reservations_booking'` and if an `IntegrityError` occurs, instead of inserting in the first table, I want it to insert to the second table. The problem is, even if it's in the except block it's still try to execute the insert to the first table. I would really appreciate any help.

```
from psycopg2.errors import ForeignKeyViolation, UniqueViolation
from sqlalchemy import exc, insert
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, sessionmaker

record = df.to_dict(orient="records")[0]

with Session(engine) as session:
    try:
        session.execute(insert(reservations_booking).values(record))
        session.commit()
    except exc.IntegrityError as e:
        session.rollback()
        if isinstance(e.orig, UniqueViolation):
            record["flag"] = "amendment"
        elif isinstance(e.orig, ForeignKeyViolation):
            record["flag"] = "not mapped"
        session.execute(insert(reservations_booking_staging).values(record))
        session.commit()
```

Comment: Works for me. If you pass `echo=True` to `create_engine`, what output do you get (please [edit] the question to include the relevant output).

Comment: Something funny happened.

So I added the `echo=True` to my db.py and since I'm working on jupyterlab I had to restart the kernel on my notebook and after restarting it, it was able to execute the code as intended. I've updated the code a bit as well and would appreciate any insight if my code would have drawbacks to what I intend to do.